# Stop updates of certain application in play console

Tags: android, google-play-console

I published an update with an error, I have to stop updating the application from users while the new version is being considered. How is it possible to prevent users from updating the application ?

I have tried to remove last publish in play console, but its impossible now

Comment: The answer provided below is correct. You only can stop distribution of an app that is under review or has not been rolled out 100% yet. For the future, I'd recommend you to do staged rollouts. You can set that your newest app version should be distributed to 50% of all users, and when a problem occurs, you can immediately cancel the rollout. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the app is under review you can control this Dashboard >>  bundle explorer >> select your release version >> on Top right delete this bundle keep in mind  after the published release you can't remove current app bundle mean while you can do add a new release and rollout 100%.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The release has already been published, so I can't do anything them. So I have to wait for a new update..

Comment: right . and rollout for 100%